# need help with Init.d script

Tags: init.d

I am trying to run a wireshark capture as a daemon.  I found this init.d script.

http://new.networkprotocolspecialists.com/downloads/tsharkd

it works to start dumpcap, but when I try to use

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tsharkd stop
```

I get the following:

/etc/init.d/tsharkd: 44: /etc/init.d/tsharkd: Stopping WireShark packet capture program: dumpcap: not found

The script, tsharkd is has owner and group as root and permissions set as -rwxr-xr-x

If I run the following line (the stop command for the init.d script) manually without sudo, I get the same error

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 18 --quiet --user root --group root --exec  /usr/bin/dumpcap >/dev/null && result="running." && exitval=0
```

If I run the line above with sudo it works.  I have even tried editing visudo but still no luck.  I also tried adding sudo to the line in the script.  Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The script is broken, it has an unneeded line break at the section:

```
 stop)
 echo -n
 "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
```

It should be

```
 stop)
 echo -n "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
```